# Using webRTC for html5 game

Tags: java, webrtc

I am working on HTML5 base game and for reliable data(login,register) we use WebSockets, now we are looking for a way to transmit data fast(position,rotation).
Our idea is the players send position to server, server evaluates it and sends the data to the other players.

I have read that webRTC is peer-to-peer based and this is not a thing a need.

Can i do it with webRTC or should i use another thing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Browser html5 real-time game. broadcast game state options](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38388638/browser-html5-real-time-game-broadcast-game-state-options)

Answer (score 0):

You can send data through WebRTC as you said peer-to-peer. But as you said, in your case, the data must flow first through the server, not directly from client to client, so WebRTC is not appropriate for this. You should stick with WebSockets.